# How to pipe a text file containing mongod arguments to mongod command

Tags: command-line, bash, mongodb, pipe, cat

So usually I start a mongod process with 2 arguments like this

`~$ mongod --dbpath /media/0CB6-189A/linux/mongodb/data --logpath /media/0CB6-189A/linux/mongodb`.

But I don't want to specify the arguments every time, so I saved them to a text file called `mongo.txt` with this following content.

`--dbpath /media/0CB6-189A/linux/mongodb/data --logpath /media/0CB6-189A/linux/mongodb`

Then I `cat` that file and pipe it through `mongod` like this

`~$ cat mongod.txt | mongod`

But it does not work, `mongod` still uses the default value `/data/db` for the argument `--dbpath` and same for the other argument. Does any know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `mongod $(cat mongod.txt)`?  You could also look into aliases.

Comment: @earthmeLon so based on your comment. I've added `mongod` to the beginning of the text file in addition to the arguments I've already had in there and it works now. Thank you. Post as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: There's a much easier approach for passing a collection of arguments to `mongod`: use a [configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) and specify this via `--config /path/to/conf` or `-f /path/to/conf`. Is there a reason you need to pipe the arguments instead?

Comment: @Stennie So in `/etc/mongod.conf` file, under the `storage` section, I changed the value of `dbPath` to my path, and under `systemLog` section, I changed `path` to the path as in my question, but when I type `mongod` on the terminal, it still shows `/data/db` as the location for the data directory and gives a write permission error because I don't run it with `sudo` that's why I need the arguments every time I run `mongod` which is annoying to be honest

Comment: Are you passing the configuration file as a parameter to `mongod` (eg: `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`)? There is no default configuration file location baked into `mongod`.

Comment: @Stennie `/etc/mongod.conf` is the default location I believe? No? Then that is probably the cause why my changes are not being read

Comment: `/etc/mongod.conf` is only used if you are running MongoDB as a service using a packaged install as per: [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). The service definition specifies the config file location when starting `mongod`. Your need `sudo` permissions to manage services, but the `mongod` process will run as an unprivileged user (`mongodb`) based on the service definition. If you want to avoid using `sudo` altogether, you can start `mongod` from any user account but will need to specify a config file location.

Comment: @Stennie Thank you so much for that. Your comment deserves a +1. If you want, post it as an answer. I'll upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path, but you're trying to pipe the output of `cat mongod.txt`.  Piping doesn't mean the output will get added as the arguments.  Instead, when you pipe data, the receiving program has to know how to deal with the pipe'd data.

For example if we have `banana.txt` with the text **Test**:

1. `cat banana.txt | echo`

   - Empty line as output
2. `echo "$(cat banana.txt)"`

   - **Test** as output

Instead of piping, we're asking `bash` to evaluate `cat banana.txt`, and insert that there immediately, and before executing `echo`.

While there are thousands of actual examples, a few examples of where you would want to pipe would be with tools like `grep` and `sed`, and `dd`.  Look into 'bash piping', 'bash evaluation/expansion',  and stuff like [STDIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29).

Comment: The issue in your example is not with piping, but with echo. Piping doesn't work with `cat file.txt | echo` simply because echo requires command-line argument, and doesn't read stdin stream provided by pipe.  If you have command that requires command-line arguments, you need `xargs`. Compare this to `cat banana.txt | xargs -L1 echo` ( which is a terrible waste of resources anyway, but for the sake of example, I'll repress the cringe ).

Comment: Additional note: if the file contains multiple lines in the file, or it's important to preserve the structure of the file ( avoid word splitting at tabs and newlines) , then quote command substitution as `"$(cat file.txt)"`

Comment: @Serg That was some extremely helpful info

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu , and all Linux distributions with GNU utilities installed, have `xargs` , which allows running a command with arguments piped from another command or from provided from stdin. In your case , what you would want to do is the following:

```
xargs  mongod < mongo_args.txt
```

Here you have `mongo_args.txt` which is the text file with your arguments, and it's being redirected as `stdin` to `xargs`. That will be joined together with `mongod` and ran as complete command.