# linux shell input redirection error

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I am trying to understand how to use input redirection in linux.
I try to use input redirection with python command.

first I use:

```sh
python -c "print('hello world')"
```

this return "hello world"

now I'd like to do the same using input redirection.

I create a file called `execute`
where I write the line:

```
-c "print('hello world')"
```

then I run
`python < execute`
and I get

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    -c 'print("hello world")'
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that putting the file contents as command arguments (the stuff after a command) is _not_ input redirection, and not what `<` does. Look up command substitution for that.

Comment: It's not totally clear why you were expecting that to work. Maybe you're confused about the word "input" in this context, so do you know the terms "standard input / stdin" and "argument"? To be clear, arguments are a form of input but not what input redirection acts on. Or maybe you're confusing input redirection (`< filename`) with command substitution of a file (`"$(< filename)"`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pipe a text file containing mongod arguments to mongod command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877054/how-to-pipe-a-text-file-containing-mongod-arguments-to-mongod-command)

Answer (score 4):

If you write the line `-c "print('hello world')"`, you are not writing valid Python syntax. Thus, python complains about an invalid syntax.

Write valid syntax in your `execute`  file, and `python`  won't complain anymore:

```
$ cat execute 
print('hello world')

$ python < execute
hello world
```

While your attempt for redirection, `python < execute`, will certainly work, there is no need to work this way. The executable python is programmed to use the name of a file you add to the command as a script. Thus, the recommended way to work is with the command:

```
python execute
```

`python` will open the file `execute` and run the commands in that file.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think that you are arguing whether `-c "print('hello world')"` should be a correct Python syntax because it isn’t and you clearly know what it is as you have actually used it correctly in the first example/method … But rather …

You are trying to understand why the command string `-c "print('hello world')"` when redirected from a file with the `<` shell redirection operator doesn’t get parsed the same way as when it’s directly put on the commandline itself, aren’t you?

Well, if you trace the first method, to see what gets actually executed, like so:

```
$ strace -e "execve" python3 -c "print('hello world')"
execve("/usr/bin/python3", ["python3", "-c", "print('hello world')"], 0x7ffcfec1b130 /* 53 vars */) = 0
hello world
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

... you would clearly see that the binary executed is `"/usr/bin/python3"` and passed `"-c"` as an option and `"print('hello world')"` as an argument.

While, if you trace the second method like so:

```
$ strace -e "execve" python3 < file 
execve("/usr/bin/python3", ["python3"], 0x7ffe6f7c4080 /* 53 vars */) = 0
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    -c "print('hello world')"
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

... you can clearly see that it's not what you expected (*and let's just leave it here*) and keep it simple by saying that shell redirection works but it doesn't place the option and argument on the commandline itself but rather feed all file contents to the Python interpreter.

Compare that to using a tool that can actually place those on the commandline itself .e.g `xargs` like so:

```
$ cat file
-c "print('hello world')"
$
$ <file xargs python3
hello world
```

Comment: thanks ! this is exactly the explanation I was looking for

Comment: @yoshcn, If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.